# What do negative cost values mean in Appstats?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appstats

Appstats is showing negative values for some of my requests on my Google App Engine development server. For example,

```
real=3604ms api=0ms overhead=1ms (13 RPCs, cost=-3588220, billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:4, DATASTORE_WRITE:-35885])
                        #RPCs     Cost
memcache.Get                4        0  
memcache.Set                3        0  
datastore_v3.RunQuery       2      210       DATASTORE_READ:3
datastore_v3.Get            1       70       DATASTORE_READ:1
datastore_v3.Put            1 -3588500       DATASTORE_WRITE:-35885
memcache.Delete             1        0  
search.DeleteDocument       1        0
```

Is a negative cost the same as a positive cost, but for delete operations?

Comment: This is likely a bug. It wouldn't make sense for you to be paid money for deleting entries from the datastore. If this is still an issue, perhaps report it as a bug to Google?